# New table column, for every echo'd checkbox (php, mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, echo, html-table, implode

I am using the script below to display checkboxes based on what is in my mySQL table by using explode/implode. It then echoes either a checked checkbox or an unchecked checkbox based on what the location field in my table contains (e.g., Vip area,Raised Area, Garden Area).

```
<?


$aColors = array("Upstairs Function Room", "Whole Raised Area", "VIP Area", "Piano Area", "DJ Table" , "Canopy area" , "Garden Area", "Whole Bar", "Back Bar Tables" , "Raised Area Table 1", "Raised Area Table 2", "Raised Area Table 3", "Raised Area Table 4", "Raised Area Table 5", "Raised Area Table 6");

//converting comma separated into array using explode function
$dbcolors= explode(',',$row['location']);

foreach ($aColors as $locations) {

    if(in_array($locations,$dbcolors)) {
        echo "<input name=\"locations[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$locations\" CHECKED> $locations <br> ";
    } else
    {
        echo "<input name=\"locations[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$locations\"> $locations <br>";
    }
}
?>
```

This works fine but I can only get it to echo a long list of checkboxes... What I would like is to display it in a table and say for every 5 checkboxes that are displayed a new column created (effectively I should end up with about 3 columns) but I am stumped at how I can achieve this... Any help is much appreciated.

Rob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trivial way would be a counter `$i` that you initialize with `$i = 0` outside the `foreach`  and increment it with `$i++` inside the foreach, then every time `$i % 5 == 0` is true you start a new column (`echo '</td><td>'`).

If you have additional styling it might be easier to split the array with [array_chunk()](https://www.php.net/array%20chunk) like this: `foreach (array_chunk($aColors, 5) as $block) {  }` and access them with `$block[0]`, `$block[1]` ... `$block[4]` inside the `foreach`.

Comment: Thank you, I pretty much sussed it with the info you provided! for anyone interested ill paste the changes below:

Answer (score 0):

final working code...

```
        <?


$aColors = array("Upstairs Function Room", "Whole Raised Area", "VIP Area", "Piano Area", "DJ Table" , "Canopy area" , "Garden Area", "Whole Bar", "Back Bar Tables" , "Raised Area Table 1", "Raised Area Table 2", "Raised Area Table 3", "Raised Area Table 4", "Raised Area Table 5", "Raised Area Table 6");

//converting comma separated into array using explode function
    $dbcolors= explode(',',$row['location']);
     $i = 0;     

          echo "<table border='0'><tr>    <td>";   

  foreach ($aColors as $locations) {

      $i++ ;


      if ($i % 5 == 0) {echo "</td>
    <td>";}

     if(in_array($locations,$dbcolors)) {
      echo "<input name=\"locations[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$locations\" CHECKED><span style='font-size:9px;'> $locations</span> <br> ";
          } else
          {
      echo "<input name=\"locations[]\" type=\"checkbox\" value=\"$locations\"> <span style='font-size:9px;'> $locations </span><br>";
                  }
              }

               echo "</td>
  </tr>
</table>";
?>
```